# Clear Contents of excell sheet from command button in Windows form (VSTO)

Tags: vb.net

I have a Windows Form on a worksheet called Position. However, I would like to put a command button that clears the values of cell H45, H46 and I49 in sheet Position and also clears the values of  I49 and H49 in sheet Calculations.

I am new to VSTO so I am having some trouble getting this done.

Can someone help on this? I am not sure how to reference the Calculation sheet from my button.

Comment: Can you post some of your code, showing what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming this is a document level Excel project? You can use the following:

```
Private Sub btnClearCells_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClearCells.Click
    With Globals.Sheet1
        .Range("H45:H46").ClearContents()
        .Range("I49").ClearContents()
    End With

    With Globals.Sheet2
        .Range("H49").ClearContents()
        .Range("I49").ClearContents()
    End With
End Sub
```

Where Sheet1 would be the Positions sheet and Sheet2 would be the Calculations sheet. Change the numbers to suit your project.

Comment: Thank you. This was extremely helpful and set me on my way to working with VSTO.